# jquery - array from select children span text separated by commas

Tags: jquery, text

I need to generate an array like this in JQuery:

```
one,two,three,four
```

by selecting the text from multiple `<span>` children:

```
<div id="GROUP">
    <div><input value="somevalue"/><span>one</span></div>
    <div><input value="somevalue"/><span>two</span></div>
    <div><input value="somevalue"/><span>three</span></div>
    <div><input value="somevalue"/><span>four</span></div>
</div>
```

I've tried with this:

```
$('html').find('#GROUP span').text();
```

But it joins all the text with no spaces:

```
onetwothreefour
```

I need to separate the text with commas

---

#### Solved

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7vdKW/2/)

Comment: You don't have to change your title as resolved instead mark any one of the answers as accepted to show your acceptance to other future visitors of this post... :) you can see a tick mark present in every answer use that... And this is not a compulsion... Just trying to teach the system... :)

Comment: i was waiting 11 min :) Sure, I accept it now :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) along with [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to collect those values in an array, afterwards [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) that array with any character you want.

```
var text = $('#GROUP span').map(function(){ 
    return $(this).text(); 
}).get().join();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zWtD6/)

**Side Note:** By default `.join()` would join the text by using `,`. So there is no need to specify that in our case.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Comment: @user3746998 It was a typo, as a pgmer, you should have corrected of your own rather complaining to me..! Anyway i updated..

Answer (score 2):

For getting them in array, you can use:

```
var spantexts= [];
$("#GROUP span").each(function() { spantexts.push($(this).text()) });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X3hjX/)**

For getting them in as comma seprated value:

Using join:

```
console.log(spantexts.join(','));
```

or

```
var spantexts= "";
$("#GROUP span").each(function() { 
    if(spantexts!="")
    spantexts+=",";
    spantexts+=$(this).text(); 
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5YX75/)**

Comment: you'd have to the use .join(): ```spantexts.join(',')```

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Really..? or kidding..?

Answer (score 0):

As a minor update, the same using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
let joinedText = $('#GROUP span').map(
    (index, domElement) => $(domElement).text()
).get().join(',');

$('#RESULT').text(joinedText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Given:
<div id="GROUP">
    <div><input value="somevalue"/><span>one</span></div>
    <div><input value="somevalue"/><span>two</span></div>
    <div><input value="somevalue"/><span>three</span></div>
    <div><input value="somevalue"/><span>four</span></div>
</div>

Result:
<div id="RESULT"></div>
```